# Creating neat map in basemap using simplified boundaries?

Tags: matplotlib-basemap

Is it possible to create a neat map like using basemap (`mpl_toolkits.basemap`)? I am particularly curious to know if there's a way to "simplify" the boundaries as they are rather edgy in the current version on basemap?

This neat map is borrowed from cartopy http://scitools.org.uk/cartopy/docs/latest/examples/features.html

[image: enter link description here]